# Can i integrate ckeditor4 's plugin in ckeditor5?

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor4.x, ckeditor5

I was trying to integrate a ckeditor4's slider [slideshow](https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/slideshow) in ckeditor5 but got an error like 'CKEDITOR is not define' in plugin.js file. Any idea?

[image]

[image: CKEDITOR is not define - error]